# I would like to Pivot column data related to one entity into one row in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I am selecting data specific to certain clients out of multiple tables where data from one client spans multiple rows, however I would like duplicate entries to be combined onto one row.  One basic example would be as follows

```
+------------+-------+-------------------------------+
| ClientCode | Name  |             Email             |
+------------+-------+-------------------------------+
| CAL01      | Doug  | itsjustdoug@internet.org      |
| CAL01      | Doug  | doug@email.com                |
| MER03      | Jane  | janehasemail@email.com        |
| MER03      | Jane  | janerocks@web.com             |
| MER03      | Jane  | janehatesspam@justforspam.net |
+------------+-------+-------------------------------+
```

The results I am looking for would be more like

```
+------------+-------+-------------------+-------------------+-----------------------+
| ClientCode | Name  |      Email1       |      Email2       |        Email3         |
+------------+-------+-------------------+-------------------+-----------------------+
| CAL01      | Doug  | itsjustdoug@inte  | doug@email.com    | NULL                  |
| MER03      | Jane  | janehasemail@ema  | janerocks@web.com | janehatesspam@justfor |
+------------+-------+-------------------+-------------------+-----------------------+
```

Here is what I have tried.

```
Select * From
(Select 
ClientCode
,Name
,Email
From dbo.Clients)  T
PIVOT(Max (Email) for Email in (Email1, Email2, Email3)) T2
```

This does not seem to be the correct way to achieve what I want.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.   It is worth noting that the actual query is much more complicated and contains many joins and perhaps several different instances where I would use this sort of "pivoting?"

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Generate `Row_number` per `clientcode` in pivot source query

And concatenate `Email` text with the generated `row_number` which will create the pivot column list

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT ClientCode,
               NAME,
               Email,
               'Email'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), Row_number() OVER(partition BY ClientCode ORDER BY email)) Emails
        FROM   dbo.Clients) T
       PIVOT(Max (Email)
            FOR Emails IN( [Email1],
                           [Email2],
                           [Email3])) T2
```

**[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c99cb/1)**